# LEFT JOIN tables and SUM values that REGEXP specific characters

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have 3 tables,and here is my table 1,Members:

```
+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
```

and my table 2,Members7:

```
+---------------+---------------------------+---------+
| TotalWorkYear |         JobScope          | user_id |
+---------------+---------------------------+---------+
|             1 | Financial;pharmacy        |       1 |
|             6 | Doctor/Diagnosis;pharmacy |       1 |
|            10 | Accounting;pharmacy       |       1 |
+---------------+---------------------------+---------+
```

And table 3,Members7_2:

```
+-----------------+----------------+---------+
| TotalWorkYear_2 | KnowledgeSkill | user_id |
+-----------------+----------------+---------+
|               1 | abc;def;       |       1 |
|               6 | vw;xyz;def     |       1 |
|              10 | vw;xyz;        |       1 |
+-----------------+----------------+---------+
```

I need to find out the user_id **that regexp 'pharmacy' in `JobScope` of `Members7`,and the total years of `JobScope` that regexp pharmacy is >=0,
and also regexp 'def' in `KnowledgeSkill` of `Members7_2`,and the total years of `KnowledgeSkill` that regexp 'def' is >=0,**

so now we can see that:

```
TotalWorkYear = 17

TotalWorkYear_2 = 7

user_id = '1'
```

And here is my query:

```
SELECT Members.user_id, 
SUM( IF( Members7.JobScope
REGEXP 'Pharmacy', Members7.TotalWorkYear, 0 ) ) yearsJobScope, Members7.JobScope AS JobScope, 
SUM( IF( Members7_2.KnowledgeSkill
REGEXP 'def', Members7_2.TotalWorkYear_2, 0 ) ) yearsSkill, Members7_2.KnowledgeSkill AS KnowledgeSkill
FROM Members
LEFT JOIN Members7 ON Members.user_id = Members7.user_id
LEFT JOIN Members7_2 ON Members.user_id = Members7_2.user_id
GROUP BY JobScope REGEXP 'Pharmacy', 
KnowledgeSkill REGEXP 'def', user_id
HAVING 
JobScope REGEXP 'Pharmacy'
AND yearsJobScope >=0
AND KnowledgeSkill REGEXP 'def'
AND yearsSkill >=0
```

but the output is:

```
+---------------+------------+
| yearsJobScope | yearsSkill |
+---------------+------------+
|            17 |        18  |
+---------------+------------+
```

and if I removed the REGEXP under HAVING,I can see that:

```
+---------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
| user_id | yearsJobScope |                  JobScope                   | yearsSkill | KnowledgeSkill |
+---------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
|       1 |             1 | Audit & Taxation;Banking/Financial;pharmacy |          6 | vw;xyz;def     |
|       1 |             6 | Doctor/Diagnosis;pharmacy                   |          6 | vw;xyz;def     |
|       1 |            10 | General/Cost Accounting;pharmacy            |          6 | vw;xyz;def     |
+---------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
```

It seems like just sum the `TotalWorkYears` of 3 rows.

Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: You also have a third table, `members` in your query.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson Yes I'm sorry,that is the first table,but since it's `user_id` only so I didn't paste it.I edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your left join with multiple tables will make some skills count more than once. The easy way to rewrite the query is with subqueries for the other tables;

```sql
SELECT m.user_id, yearsjobscope, yearsskill
FROM members m
JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, SUM(totalworkyear) yearsjobscope
  FROM members7 WHERE jobscope REGEXP 'Pharmacy'
  GROUP BY user_id) m7
  ON m.user_id = m7.user_id
JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, SUM(totalworkyear_2) yearsskill
  FROM members7_2 WHERE KnowledgeSkill REGEXP 'def'
  GROUP BY user_id) m7_2
  ON m.user_id = m7_2.user_id
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91248e/1).

As an end note, if your table gets big, `REGEX` is not a good way to do it, you'll want to at least split your semicolon separated values into rows, so that indexes/exact matches can cover them.

Comment: I see,thanks for the information,I seriously still lack of knowledge about SQL.And the query works so perfectly,really thanks for your help.And lastly,thanks for your advices,I will recreate the table structure.